# Convert capture group to named capture group

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group

How would i approach converting simple capture groups to named capture groups, if i were to provide the names as a list, i normally program in python, but open to other languages that may help achieve this.

**Basic Example:**

Regex:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)
```

Names:

```
["ip","name","proto","http_status_code"]
```

End result regex:

```
(?<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(?<name>\w+)\s(?<proto>\w+)\s(?<http_status_code>\d+)
```

regex_data_to_test:

```
"172.16.1.1 bob tcp 200"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, though it would get pretty tricky if you ever have nested parentheses:

```
reg = r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)"
groupNames = ["ip","name", "proto", "http_status_code"]

splitReg = [a for a in reg.split("(") if a] # skip empty groups
if len(groupNames) == len(splitReg):
    newReg = ''.join([("(?P<" + name + ">" + val) 
        for name, val in zip(groupNames, splitReg)])
    print(newReg)
```

Output:

```
(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(?P<name>\w+)\s(?P<proto>\w+)\s(?P<http_status_code>\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `P` to every group, that is:

```
(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s
(?P<name>\w+)\s
(?P<proto>\w+)\s
(?P<http_status_code>\d+)
```

---

In `Python` this could be

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(?P<name>\w+)\s(?P<proto>\w+)\s(?P<http_status_code>\d+)')

string = "172.16.1.1 bob tcp 200"

for m in rx.finditer(string):
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Which yields

```
{'ip': '172.16.1.1', 'name': 'bob', 'proto': 'tcp', 'http_status_code': '200'}
```

See a demo for your expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/a1tQBa/1).

---

Note, that if you always have this format, you could easily split and unpack:

```
string = "172.16.1.1 bob tcp 200"
ip, name, proto, status = string.split()

print(ip)
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, i get how to make regular named capture groups in python , sorry forgot to add the "P" as i working with PCRE before haha.

Comment: i guess the proper question would be is how to map those names into capture groups , instead of manually going in and adding them.